# what's wrong with my transaction...?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

**emp1 table**

```
id name    sal

4  hr      10000  
5  crm     20000
```

**emp table**

```
id name sal

4  hr   10000  
5  crm  20000
```

while running the below query my emp1 table is effecting
and it is not rollback..? can any one help me

```
BEGIN TRAN T1

DELETE FROM EMP1 WHERE ID=5

DELETE FROM EMP WHERE ID=11

COMMIT TRAN T1

BEGIN

PRINT 'SUCCES FULLY DELETED'

ROLLBACK TRAN T1


END
```

expected O/P is   should not effect on emp1 and emp if any statement fails........

Comment: Why are you commiting the transaction if you want it rolled back?

Comment: The logic of the script is confusing. Should the delete statements be committed or rolled back?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want something like this to happen?

```
begin try
  BEGIN TRAN T1

  DELETE FROM EMP1 WHERE ID=5

  DELETE FROM EMP WHERE ID=11

  COMMIT TRAN T1

  PRINT 'SUCCES FULLY DELETED'
end try
begin catch
  if @@trancount > 0

    ROLLBACK TRAN T1

end catch
```

Comment: so in case one of the delete statements fail then nothing is commited (in case second delete fails the first one is not deleted - in your initial code if the second statement failed the first would still be committed...